# Mechanize not logging in?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

I'm very new to python, and I'm trying to scrape a webpage using BeautifulSoup, which requires a log in.

So far I have

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.open('URL')

#login form
br.select_form(nr=2)
br['email'] = 'EMAIL'
br['pass'] = 'PASS'
br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(), "lxml")
with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

(With "URL" "EMAIL" and "PASS" being the website, my email and password.)

Still the page I get in output1.html is the logged out page, rather than what you would see after logging in? 
How can I make it so it logs in with the details and returns what's on the page after log in?

Cheers for any help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `br.form['email']` instead of `br['email']`?

Comment: That didn't work either, the results I'm getting is still the page not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another way to obtain desired page.
It may be a little bit easy to troubleshoot.

1. First, you should login manually with open any browser Developer tools's page Network. After sending login credentials, you will get a line with POST request. Open the request and right side you will get the "form data" information.

[image: Chrome browser Developer tools screenshot]

2. Use this code to send login data and get response:

`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()

url = "your url"

req = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

# You can collect some useful data here (like csrf code or some token)

#fill in form data here
params = {'login': 'your login',
          'password': 'your password'}

req = session.post(url)
```

I hope this code will be helpful.

Comment: No, when I run it all the code I get is just the first page.

Comment: Have you discovered which data should be included in POST request (csrf token etc.)?